# How do I know if my computer is susceptible to bricking via rm -rf?

Tags: rm, uefi

I've heard a lot of horror stories of `rm -rf /` not only deleting the operating system (as expected) but also hard bricking the hardware of the system by deleting important firmware variables, preventing it from even turning on to reinstall the OS. How do I know, other than running `rm -rf /` and hoping for the best, if my system is susceptible to this?

My main concern is that I'll typo a command and accidentally ruin the firmware of my machine in an unrecoverable way. I don't mind if I have to reinstall the OS or reconfigure the UEFI settings, I just don't want to have to buy another computer because of a typo.

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad 310.

Comment: How did you install Linux on your computer to begin with?  Whatever you did there would work again, no?

Comment: People who are inclined to being an obnoxious jerk in the comments might find it useful to refer to (for example) the [efivarfs documentation discussion of this exact issue](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/efivarfs.txt), and to reflect on their choices in life.

Comment: You should assume that it is. I cannot think of any valid use of `rm -fr /`. `rm -fr` is very slow in the 1st place, so if you find yourself using `rm -fr` all the time to remove large trees, you should consider using loop devices / some volume manager, which will allow you to reclaim the space used by entire forests of useless files almost instantly.

Comment: @AndyDalton Not in this case, no. Deleting efivars in some cases causes the motherboard firmware to become corrupted, which means it won't even POST, let alone read an operating system off a USB/DVD.

Comment: @mosvy I don't want to assume my computer is one command away from being actually properly destroyed at the hardware level. I want to know whether it is or isn't. When you smell smoke, do you assume your house is on fire and evacuate everyone, or do you first check if your toast is burning?

Comment: @I.Am.A.Guy `bash: sudo: command not found`. What should I do now?

Comment: @Daffy your computer is one command away from being bricked. Another example is writing garbage to some offsets of `/dev/mem`.

Comment: @mosvy how can writing to `/dev/mem` cause damage that can't be solved by, at most, a reinstall of the OS?

Comment: `/dev/mem` maps memory, and by implication the kernel's representation of the EFI variables. Writing to this could have the same effect as overwriting them directly.

Comment: To avoid guesses, what would probably be useful is if you could explain what your target requirement/concern is. We've already ascertained that some systems can be bricked, but we can't be sure yours can because you've not shared your make/model. Perhaps you want to reinstall and are worried that doing so will break your computer? Perhaps it's a "just in case" question? In all these cases we can't give you 100% certainty because we're missing underlying details. Have you got the information you need? If not please provide more data.

Comment: @roaima Good point, updated my question with more clarification and my laptop's model.

Comment: @Daffy most devices have their registers mapped as "memory", in the real address space seen by the CPU and exposed to the userspace via `/dev/mem`. Writing to some offset of `/dev/mem` may turn a led connected to a GPIO on. Writing to another offset may erase some device's eeprom ;-)